# How can I make return boolean value not printed?

Tags: python, function, boolean

```
word_1 = str(input(f"Enter a string: "))
word_reversed = word_1[::-1]


def check_palindrome(input_string):
    if word_1 == word_reversed:
        return (True)
        print (f'{word_1} is a palindrome')
        
    elif word_1 != word_reversed:
        return(False)
        print(f'{word_1} is not a palindrome')  
        
print(check_palindrome(word_1))

> `Here is the output: 
Enter a string: level 
level is a palindrome 
True`
```

I want to write retun true value but make it unvisible. I should run it with the return

Comment: return exits the function and does not run the code after it. switch print and return. You are also wrapping the function in a print: remove that and it'll only print the "...a palindrome"

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
word_1 = str(input(f"Enter a string: "))
word_reversed = word_1[::-1]


def check_palindrome(input_string):
    if word_1 == word_reversed:
        print (f'{word_1} is a palindrome')
        return (True)
        
    elif word_1 != word_reversed:
        print(f'{word_1} is not a palindrome')  
        return(False)
        
check_palindrome(word_1)
```

Comment: Yesss!!! It worked 
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
print(check_palindrome(word_1))
```

You should just write

```
check_palindrome(word_1)
```

It will still print the line you expect since the function says to print it, but if you call the function in a print statement, it will always print the return value.

Comment: thank you for your answer, first i wrote 'check_palindrome(word_1)' but the output just printed 'Enter a string: '

Comment: Make sure the print statement in the function comes before the return statement

Comment: Yepp, Now it worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use return you assign a value to the function, printing that function first runs the function, and then prints it.

To solve this you could write : return str(word1, "is a palindrome") instead of returning True and False

Comment: thank you, it i write return str(word1, "is a palindrome")  is it understand that s true? I should  state this True

Comment: no it will not, if you want to assign True to the function value if the word is a palindrome you should write return, but then you should not print the function. Only run it by calling the name, so instead of print(check_palindrome(word)) you should just write check_palindrome(word)

Comment: Yess, I got it. 
Thanks a lot :)